# How to use AWS Signature v4 on javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

Using the AWS identity pool, i was able to generate my credentials; accesskey, secretkey, and token. I've tested it on postman and insomnia. Do you have any idea on how i can call my api gate way resources using my credentials?

Comment: Have you tried aws-sdk for javascript?

Comment: I tried this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-javascript as my reference. But i still get status 403 whenever i use the signature

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js it works well.